# Creating all satisfying models, Z3 .Net API

Tags: z3

I am using th Z3 .Net API. I have a simple piece of code in which I want to create all satisfying models. The code is like this:

```
    Solver solver = ctx.MkSolver();

    Expr x = ctx.MkConst("x", ctx.MkBoolSort());
    Expr y = ctx.MkConst("y", ctx.MkBoolSort());

    BoolExpr constraint1 = ctx.MkBoolConst("Constraint1");
    solver.AssertAndTrack(ctx.MkOr((BoolExpr)x, (BoolExpr)y), constraint1);
```

The problem is that later on in the code when I want to enumerate all the models I use this code:

```
        Model resultModel = pSolver.Model;
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}",
            resultModel.Evaluate(pX),
            resultModel.Evaluate(pY));
```

But there are some models that for example if (X = true) then (Y = Y). For these situations I want to show that infact there are two models like:

```
X = true, Y = true
X = true, Y = false
```

Is there a capability in the API that can give me these answers or should I use internal coding for getting these answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general, no. At least not in an SMT-Lib sanctioned way. When solvers present models, they are always tied to ground values and SMTLib doesn't provide any provisions for having "minimal" models. Note that what minimal means here is also not clear: In your example both `x` and `y` would've sufficed, and fixing one before the other can effect choices of other variables. Which one would you want the solver to prefer?

If you are interested in such minimal models, BDD-based solvers are your friends. Since you fix a variable order in a BDD, you can read off the "minimal" model according to that variable order easily. But SMT solvers usually don't expose such details, nor they will allow you easy access to if they had such engines. In the particular case of Z3, you might want to ask at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to see if there might be a low-level API to get something more useful; but obtaining such "symbolic" models is not something SMT-solvers provide in general.